# Mixing Z3 c and c++ apis

Tags: z3

Why does the following code not work ? I get a runtime error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "z3++.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    z3::context c;
    z3::expr a = c.bv_val(12,16);
    Z3_ast a0 = Z3_mk_extract(a.ctx(),0,0,a);
    Z3_ast a1 = Z3_mk_extract(a.ctx(),1,1,a);
    Z3_ast a2 = Z3_mk_extract(a.ctx(),2,2,a);
    cout << Z3_ast_to_string(a.ctx(),a0);
    cout << Z3_ast_to_string(a.ctx(),a1);  // <-- BOOM
    cout << Z3_ast_to_string(a.ctx(),a2);
}
```

if i only use the C api, it works perfectly. I thought i could mix the two api easily...

A.G.

Comment: At a glance, this appears to be C++. Which C are you referring to?

Comment: I believe Z3_ast_to_string is a C style API of Z3 and z3::context / z3::expr is from the c++ API.. but I'm not familiar with Z3

Comment: @Logicrat Z3_* functions are from the C API.

Comment: @Heyji Thanks. I was just coming to that conclusion after looking at Z3++.h for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C API functions, such as Z3_mk_extract, you have to maintain reference counters on created objects yourself. The C++ wrapper automatically increases a reference counts in the "expr" class.
So one way of fixing the code is to wrap a0, a1, a2 in exprs. E.g., you can say:

```
 z3::expr a0 = z3::expr(c, Z3_mk_extract(a.ctx(),0,0,a));
```

Comment: In the description of the Z3_mk_context_rc() function, it is written that if you use Z3_mk_context() instead, you don't need to maintain the reference counters. I never maintain these counters with the C API, and I use the latter context creation function. So it seams a little bit trickier. I have just seen that the context class of the c++ API uses Z3_mk_context_rc() to init its context...that explains it.